# What is the solution for authorizing linux users?

Tags: linux, authorization

Entire company uses Linux distributions for users and and servers solutions.

Company employees, when authenticate themselves to pc and are connected do company internal network, should get authorization for various internal applications accesable over web interface, file servers and other utility services. Users can fork from home, offshore and so on, connected over vpn or work inside company physically.

What are solutions for authorizing user for various application access and their rights ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to ServerFault.

Your question is rather broad and can not possibly be answered in a useful way without further knowledge about your environment, and it's doubtful whether it *can* be answered in this form.

For us to give you pointers on how to proceed or ask more focused follow-up questions, you would need to give details about

- the application(s) you want to protect,
- how they handle authentication and authorization,
- how they expect users to be provisioned (in their little world),
- whether they are completely under your control,
- if you are able to customize them,
- the target platforms you to support (Windows, Linux, Mobile, Web, whatever),
- whether or not you want single-sign on (SSO),
- where your user accounts live now and how that user account "store" is accessible.

Be aware that even you give details, this question can't have an exact answer, as we know nothing about what budget, what legal requirements, or other non-technical circumstances you might have that you haven't considered yet.

Comment: Hello fuero and than you for a welcome,

I understand, this is design-thinking than a straight question. But i need to 
understand how this solution could be thinked and designed.

Let's presume everything is under full control in company and the applications we want to access are various business management, accounting and so on.

All other questions you issued are also interesting to me how possibly it should be designed and what offers could be made.

Maybe there are some minds, links could be shared to make me more aware of IAM solutions to fink of ? and get deeper insights ?